# SQL Queries vs Conditions in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

If we are having an array of about 1000-2000 elements, and a mysql table of about 1000-2000 (can increase). We have to find that table content is in array or not.

**Which is a better approach?**

1. Getting an element from array and run simple mysql query like `SELECT *...... WHERE.....` (Running 1-2k sql queries)
2. Get the table stored in mysql in other array and check it's element with other. i.e. nested for-loop type. (Running 1 sql query and then 1-2k condition checks)

Comment: Where does the array come from?

Comment: you can store the mysql table data in another php array using the select query,then compare both arrays using `array_diff`

Comment: @JoeAxon the array is made from crawling data. Using html simple dom parsr..

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is: try it.

The almost obvious answer is: doing queries is often faster than iterating through arrays in php. One query is much faster than multiple queries due to less overhead.

This is where i would start:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE something IS IN ('a1', 'a2', ..., 'a1000')
```

Answer (score 0):

scraping data with html simple dom parser is slow, as compared with the built-in dom parser DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

searching large php arrays with 1000+ elements is going to be slower then querying a db.

it could be more efficient to bulk insert the php array to db and query in sql. bulk inserts have considerations like table type (MyISAM|InnoDB etc), disabling keys, large amounts of index's blah blah blah.

at the end you'll need to benchmark.