# PHP Conditional vs MySQL Conditional

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to display the data from 'table' if a key inputted by the user is found in the database. Currently I have it set up so that the database checks if the key exists, like so:

```
//Select all from table if a key entry that matches the user specified key exists
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` = :key)';
//Prepare the SQL query
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
//Substitute the :key placeholder for the $key variable specified by the user
$query->execute(array(':key' => $key));

//While fetched data from the query exists. While $r is true
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //Debug: Display the data
    echo $r['data'] . '<br>';
}
```

These aren't the only SQL statements in the program that are required. Later, an `INSERT` query along with possibly another `SELECT` query need to be made.

Now, to my understanding, using `WHERE EXISTS` isn't always efficient. However, would it be more efficient to split the query into two separate statements and just have PHP check if any rows are returned when looking for a matching key?

I took a look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066884/sql-queries-vs-conditions-in-php), however it compares multiple statements on a much larger scale, as opposed to a single statement vs a single condition.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use a JOIN

Comment: I'm still fairly new to most of the different SQL statements. Could you point me in the right direction on how to implement this?

Comment: Show the structures for your `table` and `keys` tables

Comment: In keys I have an Auto Increment 'id' along with a varchar 'key' and in table I have a string 'title'

Comment: You have no id of any kind on `table`? So what exactly is the relationship between `table` and `keys`? Or do you simply want to get ___every___ record from `table` if the user has entered a valid `key`?

Comment: I also have an auto inc id in 'table' but nothing else. Yes, I want to display all records if a valid key is entered.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN keys ON key=:key (with backticks as appropriate, they don't show well in comments) if you need to do the authentication and the data retrieval in a single select statement

Comment: Thank you for the help, Mark Baker. It's now working correctly. But is it good practice to have SQL do tasks in this manner or should I just have PHP do this authentication check and display the rows based on that?

Comment: It isn't generally good practise to do both authentication and selection of data in this way because there is no direct correlation between the data in the tables

Comment: Should there be direct correlation? If so, what would I need to include? If not, is there a better approach to this?

Comment: There should be a direct correlation for retrieval of data; the join in my SQL SELECT (or the WHERE EXISTS in yours) are using a non-existent relationship between the tables: relational databases are called relational for a reason, so while this code works, it breaks relational principles.... it would also "break" if there was more than one record with the same value of `key` that had been selected, returning every value from `table` twice

Comment: I understand now. Then it would make more sense to keep the data separate based on the way I have it set up and to use two separate SQL statements instead, one for authentication and one for data retrieval. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MarkBaker `Join` doesn't have to be faster than `exists` statement. Query optymalizer is able to rewrite the query live if it sees better way to accomplish query. `Exists` statement is more readable than `join`.

Fetching all the data and making filtering directly in PHP is always bad idea. What if your table grow up to milions of records? MySQL is going to find the best execute plan for you. It will automaticaly cache the query if it is going to improve performance.

In other words, your made everything correctly as far as we can see your code now. For futher analyse show us all of your queries.